# How do I plot one measure per axis in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a problem that I have reduced to its essence with the following CSV file. Imagine we're a company that sells potatos and apples, and each customer is assigned a potato-class and an apple-class.

[image: Contents of the CSV]

What I want is to plot the sales according to class - so apple sales by apple class and potato sales by potato class, in one diagram. Dragging all the measures into a workheet, I get this:

[image: 4x4]

So I would like an overlay of the top left and bottom right classes.
If I combine everything into one diagram via dual axis, I get this:

[image: One_diagram]

So Tableau is plotting potato sales and apple sales on both the potato and the apple class axis, creating four dots per class where I want two.

Does anyone have an idea on how to basically assign one measure to one axis instead of both measures to both axes? (Hiding the "wrong" dots would also be fine).

Also, I realize that pivoting the dataset to have fields "sales", "class" and "product" would solve the problem, but reality is of course far more complicated than this toy example and it's just not feasible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely have an easier time if you reshape your data first, say to have the following columns "Customer,Item,Class,Amount" -- so each row in your original data set would yield 2 rows in the transformed version of your data set. Tableau Prep can make those types of transformations easy (and repeatable), but it is possible to do something similar in Tableau Desktop alone (using a self-union and some calculated fields).

So the first 2 lines might be:

```
Customer,Item,Class,Amount
1,"Apple",1,2
1,"Potato",1,4
```

Either way make sure Class is treated as a dimension in Tableau.

Data wranglers often call this a tall format instead of a wide format.

Comment: In my opinion too, data needs to be reshaped.  Unlike MS Excel, tableau prefers long data format  A simple logic to know when data needs reshaping in tableau, is that any variable values (in this example apple, potato, etc.) should never be in variable names (i.e. column names)..  +1

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, pivoting the dataset like this isn't feasible in my situation. It comes out of an ETL pipeline and this dashboard isn't the only consumer of this table, so I can't simply change it. Also the size is pretty large as it is (both row and column numbers), so I think that the extract refresh would take forever in both cases...

Comment: You don’t have to replace the original data source or impact anyone else. Tableau Prep let’s you specify rules that transform data from one layout to another (called a flow). The flow can be executed whenever the data changes to allow your official data source to remain as is, but drive your visualization from a structure that is well tuned to your problem. Try it on a small subset to see if it helps before dismissing the approach. It’s quite normal to reshape data for visualization

Comment: Even simpler reshape a small number of rows by hand in a test file. See if you can find a structure that makes the visualization you want easy to create. The look at how to cause the reshaping, either with Tableau Prep or Tableau Desktop’s data source page